# Is it worthwhile to build a competive Standard M15 deck when a block is about to rotate out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I want to start playing competitive magic again, in the standard format (just started up again after about 6 years of not playing).

Is it worth it for me to build a competitive standard deck right now, considering that the RTR block will be rotating out and most competitive decks contain RTR cards? Or should I just play draft right now to build up cards that will be in the Theros block and will still be legal In standard play come this fall, and wait to see what decks are still competitive this fall after the new set rolls in?

Comment: "Should" by what standard?  We need to know what you want out of Magic before we can tell you how to get there.  How many games do you want to play, and how often?  How many do you want to win, and how often (and how soon)?  How much money do you have to blow?  Etc.

Comment: Well, there's standard tournaments at my local shop every Friday and Sunday that I'd like to attend. I would like to win them all lol. And I'm not rich, but I've got some extra money to put towards. Essentially I feel like id waste my money building a competitive deck right now, especially with cards that are about to rotate out. So I suppose my goal would be to gain as many cards that will still be relevant in a month out of M15 and theros block.

Answer (score 2):

I would seriously consider waiting for the rotation. Two, possibly three of the major decks (namely U/W Control, Mono-Black Devotion and possibly Mono-Blue, whose competitiveness will depend on on the strength of red in Tarkir block) will be completely transformed or outright lost to rotation.

I would focus on getting the key cards from Theros block/M15 that are safe vet to be used in decks after rotation. Stuff like [Hero's Downfall](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hero%27s%20Downfall), [Sylvan Caryatid](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sylvan%20Caryatid), [Courser of Kruphix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Courser%20of%20Kruphix), [Stormbreath Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stormbreath%20Dragon), [Nissa, WorldWaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nissa%2C%20WorldWaker), [Elspeth, Sun's Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Elspeth%2C%20Sun%27s%20Champion) etc.